# How to install buildx with docker 23.0.1

Tags: docker, buildx

I am trying to install buildx from docker [doc](https://docs.docker.com/build/install-buildx/). At first, I tried [Install using a Dckerfile](https://docs.docker.com/build/install-buildx/#install-using-a-dockerfile). I have to say, I have no clue how to install it with this steps, the instructions is very poor for this section. So I pick option [Download manually](https://docs.docker.com/build/install-buildx/#download-manually).

I downloaded **buildx-v0.10.2.darwin-amd64** binary, copy it to `$HOME/.docker/cli-plugins` and rename it as `docker-buildx` and make it executable:

```
$ ll $HOME/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 55984928 Feb 14 20:05 /root/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx*
```

All this steps are from documentation.

As next step, I wanted to [Set Buildx as the default builder](https://docs.docker.com/build/install-buildx/#set-buildx-as-the-default-builder). According to the docs, I shuld run `docker buildx install` but it raised and exception `'buildx' is not a docker command`:

```
$ docker buildx install
docker: 'buildx' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'
```

The instructions are very unclear to me and dont know how to fix it. I found [this](https://bobcares.com/blog/docker-buildx/) but its basically the same steps so its do not help.

Can anybody help me to find out, whats I am missing?

```
$ uname -m
x86_64
```

Docker version 23.0.1, build a5ee5b1

Comment: Are you running docker, and not a competing project like podman? Docker includes buildx out of the box.

Answer (score 6):

On Debian you can install plugin package (see [official install instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/)):

```
apt install docker-buildx-plugin
```

similar on RedHat/CentOS:

```
yum install docker-buildx-plugin
```

then run:

```
docker buildx install
```

or update `/etc/docker/daemon.json` with (and restart `docker` service):

```
{
  "features": {
    "buildkit" : true
  }
}
```

Then `docker info` should be showing something like this:

```
$ docker info | head -n8
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:    24.0.6
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.11.2
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to simply do `sudo apt install docker-buildx` & then did `wsl --shutdown`.

After that, I tried `docker build . -t node-app` which worked without showing the error:

> DEPRECATED: The legacy builder is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
> Install the buildx component to build images with BuildKit:
> https://docs.docker.com/go/buildx/

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

1. Download buildx-v0.10.2.darwin-amd64 to `$HOME/.docker/cli-plugins`
2. Don't rename it
3. Run the following command: `$ docker buildx install`

See if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Docker Engine package repositories contain Docker Buildx packages when installed according to the [Docker Engine install documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/). Install the docker-buildx-plugin package to install the Buildx plugin.

Still if you want to **Manual download** then follow below steps

- Download buildx binary from below URL as per your OS architecture :

  https://github.com/docker/buildx/releases/
- Rename the binary to **docker-buildx**
- Place the binary in the below path : `$HOME/.docker/cli-plugins`
- Set the environment path and source the file

Source:

https://github.com/docker/buildx#installing

---

Commands logs:

```
$ docker buildx version
    github.com/docker/buildx v0.10.5 86bdced7766639d56baa4c7c449a4f64684787

$ docker info 
Client:
 Version:    24.0.2-rd
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 -----
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.10.5
    Path:     /Users/Shubh/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
 -----
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.18.1
    Path:     /Users/Shubh/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
```

Answer (score -1):

first execute

```
~/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
```

and see if you can execute it.
if it is not executable then `docker buildx install` will fail

Comment: This is not a solution, just a check. Is the solution to make it executable?

Comment: @DannyThunder if the binary is not executable, you will need to use chmod to make it executable. Then docker buildx install will work. It is not a check, it is a proper solution.